# Using getters and setters from parent class in child class

Tags: python, oop, python-class

I'm trying to get a method in my child class to set attributes from the parent class as follows:

My parent class:

```
class user_credentials:
    
    def __init__(self):  
        self.username= ""

# -----------------------------
# Getters & setters for attributes
#------------------------------

@property
def username(self):
    return self._username

@username.setter
def username(self, username):
    while (username == ''):
        username = input('Enter a proper User name, blank is not accepted')
    self._username = username
```

In my child class I want to set the attributes in a method as follows:

```
# Manage login requests for user
class login_manager(user_credentials):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.success_value = None
        self.error_message = None
    
    def request_login(self):
        super(login_manager, self).username = input("Enter your user name")
```

When I call the object to carry out `request_login` method:

```
lm1 = login_manager()
lm1.request_login()
```

I get the following error traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-a712c3363bb9> in <module>
      1 lm1 = login_manager()
----> 2 lm1.request_login()
      3 lm1.login_request_success()
      4 lm1.print_members()

<ipython-input-8-def865430eaf> in request_login(self)
     12     def request_login(self):
  
---> 14         super(login_manager, self).username = input("Enter your user name")

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'username'
```

I've been doing some research on this but I can't seem to find an example of someone trying to use setter from parent class in child class.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This will actually throw the error `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'email'`.

Comment: Python is not Java, if your getters or setters don't have anything useful to do (like yours), you don't write any.

Comment: Either way, classes inherit methods and all other descriptors (like properties). Just use `self.email = input("Enter your user email")`. The entire point about properties is that you usually *don't* have to know whether an attribute is a property.

Comment: @KlausD. - I have massively simplified the class - there will be further items in the getters and setters I want to be carried out just removed them to simplify the problem...

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @KlausD. - I've updated to show what my setter for username looks like and how I'd like to use it in the child class

Comment: @quamrana - I have updated

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - I've updated the question to show why I want to access the setter... using self.attribute won't allow the setter to do the checking I want it to do (please see above)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Why won't using self.attribute won't allow the setter to do the checking? There's only one implementation of ``self.username``, it *has* to use the setter which *has* to do its check. What checking do you want the setter to do, and what checking doesn't it do when accessed directly?

Comment: Note by the way that conventionally a ``property`` should behave "as if" it were an attribute. In specific, attributes generally don't pause and ask the user to override their value if they don't like it. Getting valid input *from the user* should be the responsibility of ``request_login``; ``username`` should just abort when given invalid data.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi ahaa I see - so I was using self._username and this wasn't accessing the contents in the setter. I changed to self.username and it worked. I am a bit confused though when I access _username that's the attribute of parent class but when I do self.username I am accessing the setter?

Comment: Both ``self._username`` and ``self.username`` are defined by the parent class. Conversely, you actually want to access both the same way ("as defined on the parent"). You're probably overthinking this a bit; there *is* some depth that make properties behave like attributes and that one is rather complicated, but for your (and many other) usecases you can treat both as the same kind of black box.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - this is been very useful thank you. One last point, I'm trying to wrap my head around. If I should not by convention have my property check valid user input than would there by any point in my parent class called user_credentials? I basically want this parent class to do all the checking for username, password etc. and than login manager is accessing these and providing user with means to input, check overall login success etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This edit works for me.

```
def request_login(self):
        self.username = input("Enter your user name")
```

The `super` mechanism and the `property` getter and setter syntax actually really confuse me, so I can't really tell you why your code *shouldn't* work. But since you're inheriting from the parent class anyway, you should just be able to use its methods as long as you didn't write another version in the child class.

Comment: Yes, likewise - I'm not sure why it doesn't allow me to access setter through the super method... this works in the way I want it to though - thanks.

Comment: Unless I'm missing some typo, my guess is that the complicated ways `super` and descriptors get to their underlying method calls had some assumptions that failed when combined like this.